# Can I remove a member from a Redis sorted set iff the member's score has **not** changed (without using Lua)?

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis...

Can I remove a member from a sorted set if the member's score has **not** changed?

Note: I know that I can do the following:

```
WATCH my-set
... [do some other stuff] ...
MULTI
ZREM my-set my-member
EXEC
```

But I believe this will abort the transaction (i.e. not execute ZREM) if **any** member of the set has changed. I'm only interested in aborting the transaction if `my-member` score has changed.

Can I achieve this without using server-side Lua?

Thanks!

Comment: What about storing individual ZSET members as a key? This would be able to solve the issue you have.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I don't think it will work for me because I believe I need the features of zset; in particular zrangebyscore. (Briefly, I'm setting the score to be the updated time of a resource and then using zrangebyscore to grab range of resources that have not been updated in the last 10-minutes).

Comment: What about using simple `K=V` and ZSET together?